# Stored procedure - A constant expression was encountered in the ORDER BY list, position 2

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have written a stored procedure below in MSSQL. It's throwing error in the ORDER BY clause.

a) It works fine if I put only one condition in ORDER BY clause.

b) I am not sure why it is executing both conditions of the CASE statement in the ORDER BY clause while executing the procedure. Ideally if the first condition is met, it should skip the second.

The error message is:

> Error: Msg 408, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   A constant expression was encountered in the ORDER BY list, position 2.

This is the query:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM tb_officemaster
 WHERE 1 = 1
     AND officecity LIKE '%gurgaon%'
     AND minprice > 100
     AND maxprice < 1000
 ORDER BY
     CASE WHEN 'priceasc'='priceasc' THEN "minprice" END ASC,
     CASE WHEN 'pricedesc'='priceasc' THEN minprice END DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at your `CASE` expression in your `ORDER BY` clause as below. Here the condition `'priceasc'='priceasc'` is a constant expression and is always true no matter what and actually doesn't really makes any sense. It will not evaluate to anything. `ORDER BY` somehow has to evaluate the given expression  to a row's value and order accordingly. In your case, `THEN "minprice"` is as well a constant.

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN 'priceasc'='priceasc' THEN "minprice"  END ASC
```

Per your posted query, the `order by` clause doesn't make sense and you can just omit it. Your query can simply be

```
select  * 
from tb_officemaster 
where 1=1 
and officecity like'%gurgaon%' 
and minprice >100 
and maxprice < 1000
```

Per your comment, change your `ORDER BY` to be like below

```
ORDER BY CASE  WHEN pricedesc = priceasc THEN minprice END DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul, in the above line its not constant its the parmeters i am passing via stored procedure.

Comment: ORDER BY CASE WHEN 'priceasc'='priceasc' THEN "minprice"  END ASC ..Here priceasc is the parameter,that meas the first condition is true .Here what is happening is my second condition is also getting executed..

Comment: @KapilS, then remove the single quotes. That's the root of error here I believe.

Comment: i am struggling with this since afternoon,It works fine with or without the quotes.The issue is  this part of code has some unknown issue   set @dynamicsql=@dynamicsql +'  ORDER BY CASE WHEN ''priceasc''='
  set @dynamicsql=@dynamicsql +''''+@orderbydetail +''' THEN "minprice"  END (select null) ASC ,'
  set @dynamicsql=@dynamicsql +'  CASE  WHEN ''pricedesc''='''+@orderbydetail+''' THEN minprice   END (select null)  DESC '

Comment: Again for the sake of satisfaction,I remove the double quotes and same problem.This code will work fine if remove the non-matching condition in order by clause   set @dynamicsql=@dynamicsql +'  ORDER BY CASE WHEN ''priceasc''='
  set @dynamicsql=@dynamicsql +''''+@orderbydetail +''' THEN minprice  END  ASC ,'
  set @dynamicsql=@dynamicsql +'  CASE  WHEN ''pricedesc''='''+@orderbydetail+''' THEN minprice   END   DESC '